# Oracle Pivot on column larger than 4000 characters

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, clob, listagg

```
select * from
( 
    select id, type, LISTAGG(value,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 1) as value from
    (
        select 'user1' as id, 'BMW' as value,   'CAR'      as type from dual    union
        select 'user1' as id, 'Audi' as value,  'CAR'      as type from dual    union
        select 'user2' as id, 'Honda' as value, 'CAR'      as type from dual    union
        select 'user1' as id, 'Dell' as value,  'COMPUTER' as type from dual    union
        select 'user1' as id, 'Sony' as value,  'COMPUTER' as type from dual    union
        select 'user2' as id, 'HP' as value,    'COMPUTER' as type from dual 
    )
    group by id, type
)
PIVOT (max(value) FOR id IN ('user1' user1, 'user2' user2));
```

Is there a way of using the above example if the LISTAGG is to be larger than 4000 characters?

Pivot doesn't seem to work on a CLOB column. I tried to use XMLAGG with a .getClobVAl() around it. This gives me a list larger than 4000 but cannot pivot.

Comment: What are you trying to create? Some huge file? What is the purpose?

Comment: Try create a function that do the same of listaag which return a clob instead

Comment: @Art I have a feed similar to the above that is continuously increasing. I was using listagg but the limit has been broken.

Comment: @Aramillo I have used XMLAGG to get above the 4000 characters to create the comma seperated list but cannot pivot on a clob or xmltype

Comment: Please take a look at my answer, maybe could helps you.

Comment: @S_G: What is the purpose? What do you do with this data? Save this in the file? Then what? Do you convert or load data into table(s) later? This is most important I think, not how to pivot...

Comment: @Art I have a feed that is loaded into a table. The feed contains rows of data related to different objects, lets say cars for the example here. As I have many rows of the same type I want to pivot and include each types values as a comma separated list. All was working OK for me until the list became longer than 4000 characters.

Comment: @S_G: You can use `dbms_lob.substr(rtrim(extract(xmlagg(xmlelement(e, value || ',')),  '/E/text()').getclobval(), ','), 4000) as value` instead of `list_agg`. This way result is trimmed (if this is acceptable), but at least you can pivot.

Comment: Cheers for the replies. So it looks like I am restricted to 4000 characters on a pivot or listagg.